# Error trying to install wine in Ubuntu 14.10: missing or conflicting packages

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation, wine, software-center

I already tried to install it with the terminal as well as with the ubuntu-software-center, but I always get this:

```
This error could be caused by required additional software packages which
are missing or not installable. Furthermore there could be a conflict between  
software packages which are not allowed to be installed at the same time.
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try running `sudo apt-get -f` and/or `sudo apt-get update` followed by `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` and - if no errors occured - try installing wine again and inform us what happened. Greetings!